# PyMC3: how to sample from transformed random variable?

Tags: python, data-science, pymc3

I have a super basic PYMC3 question: How do you sample from a transformed RV? I need this mostly for debugging purposes.

For example:

```
import pymc3 as pm

with pm.Model():
   A = pm.Normal('A')

   B = pm.Deterministic('B', A + 1)
   # or
   B = A + 1
```

I can generate samples from A using `A.random()`, but that function is not defined for `B`. `+ 1` is a trivial transform but in case it were more involved I would like to draw some samples from the deformed `A`, i.e. `B`, to ensure everything is healthy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is just about it -- `PyMC3` requires you to first construct a model, which you have done, and then sample from the posterior (often in the presence of data!), using `pm.sample`.

The syntax you're looking for is:

```
with pm.Model():
    A = pm.Normal('A')
    B = pm.Deterministic('B', A + 1)
    trace = pm.sample(1000)

(trace['B'] == trace['A'] + 1).all()  # True
```

Comment: That's what I tried, but the `trace` object does not contain an entry for `B`.

Comment: Hm... the above works on the current release of `PyMC3`, and should work quite a ways back.  What version do you have, and how did you install it?

Comment: You are right. I tried it also with the old version I was using before and that also works. Not sure what I did there. Thanks for clearing it up.